# Is the transfer belt cleaner in a Dell 1350cnw laser printer a user serviceable part?

Tags: printer, repair

I have a Dell 1350cnw color laser printer that has developed streaks, spots, and other negative printing results. I disassembled the unit and found the transfer belt cleaner to be very dirty and seems to be the cause of my problem.

This printer is very old and I have been unable to locate a replacement part. Even after disassembly, I found that, even though I was able to gain access to the transfer belt cleaner, I could not find a way to remove it anyways, and it may be integrated as part of the entire belt assembly.

Is this a user serviceable part? Or is the printer effectively useless once it becomes unable to clean the belt?

Comment: Replace the printer and be done.

Comment: Do you realize how much it costs to replace a color laser printer? There isn't anything wrong with it other then a small strip of fiber.

Comment: Only choice since parts are no available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.dell.com/community/Printers/2130cn-How-to-replace-the-transfer-belt/td-p/3533316), the transfer belt is normally replaced by a technician. That would imply that parts of the belt assembly are not available for separate replacement.

It may be possible to buy a replacement transfer belt. I have found one for the [Dell 1355CNW](https://www.ebay.com/itm/324176588442) but I don't know if that will fit your printer. From what I can see, it appears that the 1355 is a multi-function version of the 1350, and they do seem to use the same toners, so there's hope.

Comment: That's the entire transfer assembly and includes the cleaner on the end there, facing downwards towards the belt. It may not be possible to remove it without disassembling the entire transfer belt assembly itself. You're right that it's probably not a serviceable part, unfortunately. I have seen other laser printers where this component easily slides out from the side but this is not the case for the 1350cnw.